# How use where in Python in list object

Tags: python

How to write something like this in Python?

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'where'

```
results.where(result => result.varialbe is not None).ToList()
```

Comment: `[result for result in results if result.variable]`

Comment: Something like ... `[result for result in results if result.variable != None]` that is, if you still want to check for `None` value.

Comment: ok. I understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your result is also a list you could do something like this.

```
result = [1, 4, None, "foo"]

result_list = [variable for variable in result if variable is not None]

print(result_list)
# [1, 4, "foo"]
```

Comment: but it looks like OP is trying to call a *method* on `result` value, OP hasn't clarified what that `variable` method is, so it's not clear.

Comment: OP is looking for something similar to his/her code snippet. If the OP wants to wrap it into a method this should be not a big deal. But It gives you the result the OP asked for.